# Counting Characters from an HTML File with Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, parsing

I just completed level 2 of The Python Challenge on pythonchallenge.com and I am in the process of learning python so please bear with me and any silly mistakes I may have made.

I am looking for some feedback about what I could have done better in my code. Two areas specifically:

- How could I have more easily identified the comment section of the HTML file? I used a beat-around-the-bush method that kind of found the end of the comment (or the beginning technically but it is counting from the end) and gave me some extra characters that I was able to recognize and anticipated (the extra "-->" and "-"). What condition would have better found this comment so I could put it in a new string to be counted?

This is what I wrote:

```
from collections import Counter
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html')

pagetext = ""
pagetext = (page.text)
#find out what number we are going back to

i = 1
x = 4
testchar = ""
testcharstring = ""


while x == 4:
    testcharstring = pagetext[-i:]
    testchar = testcharstring[0]
    if testchar == "-":
        testcharstring = pagetext[-(i+1)]
        testchar = testcharstring[0]
        if testchar == "-":
            testcharstring = pagetext[-(i+2)]
            testchar = testcharstring[0]
            if testchar == "!":
                testcharstring = pagetext[-(i+3)]
                testchar = testcharstring[0]
                if testchar == "<":
                    x = 3
            else:
                i += 1
                x = 4
        else:
            i += 1
            x = 4
    else:
        i += 1
print(i)

newstring = pagetext[-i:]

charcount = Counter(newstring)

print(charcount)
```

And this is the source HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>ocr</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
</head>
<body>
<center><img src="ocr.jpg">
<br><font color="#c03000">
recognize the characters. maybe they are in the book, <br>but MAYBE they 
are in the page source.</center>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<font size="-1" color="gold">
General tips:
<li>Use the hints. They are helpful, most of the times.</li>
<li>Investigate the data given to you.</li>
<li>Avoid looking for spoilers.</li>
<br>
Forums: <a href="http://www.pythonchallenge.com/forums"/>Python Challenge Forums</a>, 
read before you post.
<br>
IRC: irc.freenode.net #pythonchallenge
<br><br>
To see the solutions to the previous level, replace pc with pcc, i.e. go 
to: http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pcc/def/ocr.html

</body>
</html>

<!--
find rare characters in the mess below:
-->

<!--
```

Followed by thousands of characters and the comment concludes with '-->'

Comment: use HTML parser (eg. BeautifulSoup), which allows you to find nodes that are comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139458/217723

Answer (score 2):

I don’t have enough reputation to comment, so I must say this in an answer.
It looks clunky to use

```
    while x == 4:
```

and then do

```
    x = 3
```

whenever you want to break out of the loop.
It looks better to do

```
    while True:
```

and when you want to break out of the loop do

```
    break
```

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, you will fit right in ;)

Comment: Thx man. I appreciate  it.

Answer (score 1):

## Redundant Code

```
pagetext = ""
pagetext = (page.text)
```

The first line assigns an empty string to `pagetext`.  The second line ignores the contents already in `pagetext` and assigns a different value to the variable.

Why bother with the first statement?  It simply makes the code longer, slower, and harder to understand.

Why bother with the `(...)` around `page.text`?  They also are not serving any purpose.

## Variable Names

Variables like `i` are a double-edged sword.  You're using it as a loop index, and then you're using it to reference a found location after the loop terminates.  But `i` by itself doesn't have much meaning.  `posn` might be clearer.  `last_comment_posn` would be much clearer, though very verbose.

PEP-8 recommends using underscores to separate words in variable names: ie, use `char_count` not `charcount` etc.

## Searching for a string of characters

Python strings have built-in functions for searching for a substring in a larger string.  For instance, [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) could rapidly find the first occurrence of `<!--` in the page text.

```py
i = pagetext.find("<!--")
```

But you're not looking for the first one; you're looking for the last one.  Python again has you covered, with the reverse find function: [`str.rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind).

```py
i = pagetext.rfind("<!--")
```

But this still finds the index of the last occurrence.  You want the characters after the comment marker, so we need to skip forward 4 additional characters:

```py
if i >= 0:
    newstring = pagetext[i+4:]
```

## Improved code

```py
import requests
from collections import Counter

page = requests.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html')
page.raise_for_status()  # Crash if the request didn't succeed
page_text = page.text

posn = page_text.rfind("<!--")
print(posn)

if posn >= 0:
    comment_text = page_text[posn+4:]    # Fix!  This is to end of string, not end of comment!
    char_count = Counter(comment_text)
    print(char_count)
```